# Sample Pyspark program returns [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file

Tags: python-3.x, hadoop, apache-spark, compiler-errors, pyspark

Here is the code I am trying to run. I have set the paths for spark, hadoop, java and python. Using Java 8, Spark 2.2.1 and hadoop 2.7.5.

```
import random
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('MyFirstStandaloneApp')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
NUM_SAMPLES = 20
def inside(p):
   x, y = random.random(), random.random()
   return x*x + y*y < 1

count = sc.parallelize(xrange(0, NUM_SAMPLES)) \
         .filter(inside).count()
print("Pi is roughly %f" % (4.0 * count / NUM_SAMPLES))
```

The error I am receiving is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sample1.py", line 4, in <module>
 sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 
    115, in __init__
SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 
         283, in _ensure_initialized
SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\java_gateway.py", 
         line 80, in launch_gateway
        proc = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, env=env)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
      restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, 
     in_execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I had installed spark twice one standalone version from Apache and one from Anaconda caused problems with the paths.

Answer (score 0):

Open Anaconda Prompt-
type= python -m ipykernel install --user

Open Jupyter Notebook